# How to append a string nsxml parser iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch

I am parsing an rss and I want to appenend a string here is some code. My application crashes for and this is what is NSLogged.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendFormat:'
```

I am appending an nsmutablestring

```
  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

  //     [data appendFormat:(NSMutableString *)string]; this doesn't work either
  [data appendFormat:string]; 
data = (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

 }
```

why is my app carshing and what can I do to fix it?

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{


 [data appendFormat:string];
 [data autorelease];
 data = [[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];
```

}

Comment: this link helps you to generate the xml more easily in iphone sdk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750004/nsmutablearray-and-nsdictionary-using-for-parsed-xml-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting `NSString` pointers into `NSMutableString` pointers doesn't make the underlying objects mutable. You might fool the compiler into thinking it works, but you can't trick the runtime. `NSString`s and `NSMutableString`s are different beasts to start with, so you can't go around, take an immutable string, and pretend it's mutable. Your app crashes because of this. (The opposite, casting an `NSMutableString` into a `NSString`, works because you're *restricting* the set of possible operations on the object. You can always cast an object down to a more restrictive form, but you can rarely cast them the other way around.)

You need to work with actual `NSMutableString` objects. The easiest way to get a mutable representation of an immutable string is to use the `mutableCopy` instance method. (Don't forget to release the objects as you go.)

```
[data appendFormat:string]; 
[data autorelease];
data = [[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: there is no error but string is not appending...but is giving warning "Format is not a string litreal and no format arguments"

Comment: You probably want to use `appendString:` instead of `appendFormat:` then.

Comment: what is the diffrence just curious?

Comment: `appendString:` appends a raw string; while `appendFormat:` accepts a format string, like `@"%i %s %g"`, and a variable number of parameters to perform substitution. See [`fprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) for the general syntax, and [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for Cocoa-specific stuff. If you don't have anything to substitute, you should use `appendString:`.